# how to press enter key in HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnitDriver & FirefoxDriver.Here is my code:

```
 HtmlUnitDriver webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(false);
```

I have entered username & password using code below:

```
WebElement webElement = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath here"));
 webElement.sendKeys("some value here");
```

It works fine,it takes username & password successfully.Now I want to submit this after pressing ENTER key.So please guide me how to press ENTER key using HtmlUnitDriver object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first select an element (input, textfield ...) using `findElement`. This will return a `WebElement`.

On this object you can use the method `sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)`.

From the API :
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

```
sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)
Use this method to simulate typing into an element, which may set its value.
```

You can use http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html#ENTER

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(false);
WebElement pw = driver.findElement(By.id("XX"));
pw.sendKeys(YY);
pw.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Hi urir, I used this but giving me error:-**org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot locate element used to submit form**.

Comment: Since HtmlUnit can only do what a user can - please make sure your relevant element actually can be submitted by ENTER press in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it in pure htmlUnit (no selenium):

```java
class Test1 {
  void sendEnter(HtmlInput htmlInput) {
    Keyboard k = Keyboard();
    k.type((char) 13);
    // this method may return a Page, but I got null YMMV, shrug
    htmlInput.type(k);
  }
}
```

This will fire all related events as well.

And be careful that sending a char `\n` WON'T act as Enter.

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

That will send to the current active element. Use the `findElement` functions to specify a particular element to interact with.

Comment: Like this, has no difference to element.sendKeys()

Comment: Right, that's assuming you have a reference to an element and don't want to hit `ENTER` on wherever the focus was since the last input. Since this is what an end user is likely to do, it makes sense to emulate just that.

Comment: It might be useful to add how this reference had gotten and what defines currently active element. I've been stuggling with enter press in certain text field with htmlunitdriver.